# passing string becomes object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm passing with `marketing.reg("bum","a","b","c");` a string to a function.

In the first scope it is still a string.

After passing to the next scope it becomes an object. How to avoid it?

```
    function mktg() {};
    mktg.prototype.reg = function(nameOfEvent,a,b,c) {
    //typeof a,b,c is string
            var fktn= function(a,b,c) {
                console.log(typeof a); //is object not string
                console.log( "fktn a: ",a);
            };

            $(document).on(nameOfEvent, fktn);

    };
    var marketing = new mktg;
    marketing.reg("bum","a","b","c");
```

Comment: how is calling the fktn methos is the jquery event.

Comment: But what's the use? You can still use it right?

Comment: You are checking the type of the event object - which is an object.

Comment: I hope `function(a,b,c) {` these params are different from `function(nameOfEvent,a,b,c)`..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The variables a, b and c get replaced by the arguments of the event call "bum".

You should remove the paramters a, b and c from the function fktn.

Comment: Am I missing anything? OP question is about `Type` and your answer is totally different it seems.. Of course it will replace the params, I am not objecting it..

Comment: @irvgk The variables are not the original ones, they are overwritten by the event trigger which will pass a new argument with an object as type (in this case, maybe it's null or undefined when another event is triggered).

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are calling function `fktn` on some event.

So in your function

```
 var fktn= function(a,b,c) {}
```

The variables `a,b,c` are no more variables from function `reg` they are parameters of function `fktn`.

On every event the first called parameter will be the `event` itself which is an object, that's why you are getting `typeof` a is object.

Answer (score 1):

instead of function (a,b,c)

try something like function ("'"+a+"', '"+b+"', '"+c+"'")

This puts the VALUES of a, b and c into quotes within the parameter list and therefore means they will be of type string.

*Apologies if it's hard to read. It starts of with single quote inside double quotes, then concatenates the value of a, then concatenates with ', ' inside double quotes etc ..*